# Value of private lessons for beginners (submission wrestling)

Tags: training

I am new to wrestling, and I am considering getting into submission wrestling. The question I have is, how valuable are private lessons versus regular classes as a beginner? Can I, assuming a good instructor, get significantly more out of taking a private lesson than a regular class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general grappling perspective:

### Advantages of private lessons

1. Instruction proceeds at your speed. This can be very important if your experience level is not similar to that of other students in a group class.
2. Private lessons allow working through many iterations of instruction and attempts at a particular technique during a single session.
3. Instructor can ensure you do not acquire bad habits.

### Disadvantages

1. A variety of training partners exposes you to the range of possible styles, body types, and reactions. A single technique may work quite differently depending on the opponent.
2. Training in a group allows you to learn from others, both in direct instruction as well as observing other students.
3. If your private instructor's body type differs significantly from yours, it can be difficult to understand how adapt techniques for your body.
4. Private lessons are more expensive. This is especially true if as a beginner you need extensive rudimentary work; you end up paying for private time when regular class time could be just as good.

---

If money is an issue, I would recommend starting in a group class because of the benefits of multiple training partners. You can assess whether you progress at an acceptable rate, and I expect you can then add on or switch to private lessons.